# How is tableview implicitly reloaded when I deleted an object from realm?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a tableview where I am using SwipeCellkit for custom cell deletion. When the delete button is pressed I delete the specified object in realm,
however, I did not reload the tableview but still the tableview row has been deleted. I want to know how it has done (is realm doing implicit tableview reloading?)

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = categoryArray?[indexPath.row].name
    return cell
}

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> [SwipeAction]? {
    guard orientation == .right else { return nil }

    let deleteAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { action, indexPath in
        // handle action by updating model with deletion

        self.updateModel(at: indexPath)

    }

    // customize the action appearance
    deleteAction.image = UIImage(named: "delete-icon")

    return [deleteAction]
}

     func updateModel(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let category = self.categoryArray?[indexPath.row]
    {
        do{
            try self.realm.write {
                self.realm.delete(category)
            }
        }catch{
            print("eror deleting object")
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with the `Realm`.

This is because of the `deleteAction` that you're returning in `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` method.

More precisely, the `SwipeActionStyle.destructive` is responsible for creating a delete action.

As mentioned in the [docs](https://swipecellkit.github.io/SwipeCellKit/):

> The built-in .destructive, and .destructiveAfterFill expansion styles
>   are configured to automatically perform row deletion when the action
>   handler is invoked (automatic fulfillment).

Hope this helps